# SCIM Provisioning sends unexpected payload for user deactivation

Tags: spring-boot, okta, scim2

I implemented a SCIM 2.0 integration with Okta according to the examples listed in [their documentation](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/scim/scim-20/#determine-if-the-user-already-exists).

However, we are getting an unexpected request for a use case. If Okta sees that the user already exists but is deactivated we get a request to the `/Users/{id}` endpoint with the following payload:

```
{
  "totalResults": 1,
  "startIndex": 1,
  "itemsPerPage": 1,
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
  ],
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": {
        "formatted": "John Does"
      },
      "emails": [
        {
          "value": "test@email.com",
          "primary": true
        }
      ],
      "externalId": "113",
      "active": true,
      "id": "113",
      "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Resources": [
    {
      "name": {
        "formatted": "John Does"
      },
      "emails": [
        {
          "value": "test@email.com",
          "primary": true
        }
      ],
      "externalId": "113",
      "active": true,
      "id": "113",
      "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
      ],
      "natsRole": "nats/v1"
    }
  ],
  "active": false
}
```

The **payload** of this request uses the schema `urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse`. Because the URL pattern mandates an update to one user this seems like it may be a bug on the Okta side, but I am wondering if this is part of the SCIM spec or if we are getting this call from Okta due to a misconfiguration (I have it setup to support **Push New Users** and **Push Profile Updates** only).

Is this a bug or by design? If it is, would a spring boot controller integration need to accept a dynamic RequestBody that could be one of two schema types?

Comment: When you send a response to get/create the same user event are you sending it accurately? Not sending back something like you are seeing coming to you for deactivate? Just an idea to check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the SCIM contract, a `GET /Users/{id}` endpoint should return a json body representing the `User`. I was erroneously returning the json body for a `/Users?filter` call: `ListResponse`.

On the okta side, before updating a user's details they `GET /Users/{id}` the current user data, merge their changes in, and call the `PUT` API. It seems that, upon getting the wrong GET details, Okta merges the changes into that response and sends it back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the SCIM server/service provider and Okta is the SCIM client, and the quoted JSON payload is from Okta's SCIM client - then Okta's SCIM client is incorrect. The ListResponse structure is only used for certain responses from a SCIM service provider, never for a request from a client.